# Postgresql 14 Primary Key not working, allows duplicates

Tags: postgresql, index, primary-key, duplication

I discovered that my 3-column (integers, not null) primary key is allowing duplicates!
Then I created new unique index and replace the current one, and the problem still exists, how is that even possible!? When select is using that index, it doesn't return replicated rows, I have to force seq scan then it's found.

@edit:

```
create table balance
(customer_id integer not null, 
period_id integer not null, 
promotion_id integer not null,
-- (and few other columns)
CONSTRAINT balance_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, period_id, promotion_id)
 )
```

It was unique index promoted to PK using:

```
ALTER TABLE balance ADD CONSTRAINT balance_pk PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX balance_pk;
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to see your table and index definitions from here; do you mind adding them to your question? Steps to reproduce the problem would also be helpful.

Comment: I added it, but I don't think that would be any closer to the answer now, because there's no room for something wrong with the DDL itself, that should be quite simple, PK = no duplicates

Comment: [Works just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=57323b2982d5192757b9aac92b0a34fb) - apparently there is more to that problem than you are telling use. You need to provide a self-contained test case that shows this behaviour

Comment: That is totally random, application is inserting few thousands of records per minute, and there are just few duplicates per hour. The query application is using includes
ON CONFLICT (customer_id, period_id, promotion_id) DO UPDATE
SET points = balance.points + excluded.points

Comment: might be related to `Prevent possible corruption of indexes created or rebuilt with the CONCURRENTLY option (Álvaro Herrera)` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/14.4/